# Date/time conversion: string representation to time_t

Tags: c++, c, datetime

How do I convert a date string, formatted as `"MM-DD-YY HH:MM:SS"`, to a `time_t` value in either C or C++?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `strptime()` to parse the time into a `struct tm`, then use `mktime()` to convert to a `time_t`.

Comment: strptime() doesn't appear to be available on Windows.  Is there a good alternative?

Comment: Don't know if a good alternative on Windows, there are several open source implementations floating around that you could use.  Alternatively, if you know the date will always be in the format you provided, you can parse it into a struct tm, perhaps using sscanf, and then use mktime to get a time_t.

Comment: here's an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/11213640/1115059

Comment: @An̲̳̳drew `strptime()` is often available on Windows with a gcc compiler.   The availability is a compiler issue, not an OS one.

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of `strptime` you could use `sscanf` to parse the data into a `struct tm` and then call `mktime`.  Not the most elegant solution but it would work.

Answer (score 3):

Boost's date time library should help; in particular you might want to look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html

Answer (score 3):

Note that `strptime` mentioned in accepted answer is not portable. Here's handy C++11 code I use to convert string to std::time_t :

```
static std::time_t to_time_t(const std::string& str, bool is_dst = false, const std::string& format = "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S")
{
    std::tm t = {0};
    t.tm_isdst = is_dst ? 1 : 0;
    std::istringstream ss(str);
    ss >> std::get_time(&t, format.c_str());
    return mktime(&t);
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
std::time_t t = to_time_t("2018-February-12 23:12:34");
```

You can find string format parameters [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time).

Comment: 1) Code does not set the `tm_isdst` member.  Failing to do so can make for inconsistent results.  2) `struct tm` does allow for additional members that benefit with initialization.  Perhaps `std::tm t = { 0 };`?  3) OP's month string is numeric, not alpha, Use `"%m"` rather then `"%b"`. 4) OP used different order than YMD hms.

Comment: I've added dst option. Init with 0 is good idea. Other things can easily be adjusted as individual requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there isn't any in Standard C / C++ . There is the POSIX function `strptime` which can convert to `struct tm`, which can then be converted to `time_t` using `mktime`.

If you are aiming for cross platform compatibility, better use `boost::date_time`, which has sophisticated functions for this.

Answer (score 1):

> best way to convert a date string, formatted as "MM-DD-YY HH:MM:SS", to a time_t

Restricting code to standard C library functions is looking for the inverse of `strftime()`.  To expand [@Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/321847/2410359) general idea, uses `sscanf()`.

Use `"%n"` to detect completed scan

```
time_t date_string_to_time(const char *date) {
  struct tm tm = { 0 }; // Important, initialize all members
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(date, "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d %n", &tm.tm_mon, &tm.tm_mday, &tm.tm_year,
      &tm.tm_hour, &tm.tm_min, &tm.tm_sec, &n);
  // If scan did not completely succeed or extra junk
  if (n == 0 || date[n]) {
    return (time_t) -1;
  }
  tm.tm_isdst = -1; // Assume local daylight setting per date/time
  tm.tm_mon--;      // Months since January
  // Assume 2 digit year if in the range 2000-2099, else assume year as given
  if (tm.tm_year >= 0 && tm.tm_year < 100) {
    tm.tm_year += 2000;
  }
  tm.tm_year -= 1900; // Years since 1900
  time_t t = mktime(&tm);
  return t;
}
```

Additional code could be used to insure only 2 digit timestamp parts, positive values, spacing, etc.

Note: this assume the "MM-DD-YY HH:MM:SS" is a *local* time.

Comment: Interesting, I've never really found a use case for `%n` since I've always used the return value of `*scanf` to ensure all arguments were scanned. However, it appears `%n` (the way you use it) does this *and* ensures there's no extra gumpf following the expected string. It's not often I learn anything new about C nowadays, so kudos :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks.  The `" %n"`, in general, helps detect any required trailing text too, something the return value does not distinguish.  E.g. `"%d xyz %n"`.

Answer (score -1):

```
    static time_t MKTimestamp(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int min, int sec)
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = gmtime ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo->tm_year = year-1900 ;
    timeinfo->tm_mon = month-1;
    timeinfo->tm_mday = day;
    timeinfo->tm_hour = hour;
    timeinfo->tm_min = min;
    timeinfo->tm_sec = sec;
    timeinfo->tm_isdst = 0; // disable daylight saving time

    time_t ret = mktime ( timeinfo );

    return ret;
}

 static time_t GetDateTime(const std::string pstr)
{
    try 
    {
        // yyyy-mm-dd
        int m, d, y, h, min;
        std::istringstream istr (pstr);

        istr >> y;
        istr.ignore();
        istr >> m;
        istr.ignore();
        istr >> d;
        istr.ignore();
        istr >> h;
        istr.ignore();
        istr >> min;
        time_t t;

        t=MKTimestamp(y,m,d,h-1,min,0);
        return t;
    }
    catch(...)
    {

    }
}
```