# C++ Converting a Datetime String to Epoch Cleanly

Tags: c++, datetime, stl, boost

Is there a C/C++/STL/Boost clean method to convert a date time string to epoch time (in seconds)?

```
yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See: [Date/time conversion: string representation to time_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321793/date-time-conversion-string-representation-to-timet)

And: [[Boost-users] [date_time] So how come there isn't a to_time_t helper func?](http://archives.free.net.ph/message/20060504.123105.73e1c873.en.html#boost-users)

So, apparently something like this should work:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
using namespace boost::posix_time;

std::string ts("2002-01-20 23:59:59");
ptime t(time_from_string(ts));
ptime start(gregorian::date(1970,1,1)); 
time_duration dur = t - start; 
time_t epoch = dur.total_seconds();
```

But I don't think it's much cleaner than [Rob's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321793/date-time-conversion-string-representation-to-timet/321847#321847): use `sscanf` to parse the data into a `struct tm` and then call `mktime`.

Comment: Thanks, but one quick corrections. Last line should be dur.total_seconds()

Answer (score 3):

On Windows platform you can do something like this if don't want to use Boost:

```
// parsing string
SYSTEMTIME stime = { 0 };
sscanf(timeString, "%04d:%02d:%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
       &stime.wYear, &stime.wMonth,  &stime.wDay,
       &stime.wHour, &stime.wMinute, &stime.wSecond);

// converting to utc file time
FILETIME lftime, ftime;
SystemTimeToFileTime(&stime, &lftime);
LocalFileTimeToFileTime(&lftime, &ftime);

// calculating seconds elapsed since 01/01/1601
// you can write similiar code to get time elapsed from other date
ULONGLONG elapsed = *(ULONGLONG*)&ftime / 10000000ull;
```

If you prefer standard library, you can use struct tm and mktime() to do the same job.

Comment: Btw, if you find yourself using sscanf for time strings into a struct tm, give strptime a look. It has some time-specific formats. For the above you could use "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S"

Answer (score 1):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time.html
Should do the trick.

Comment: I was going to suggest this too -- ptime has time_from_string() to go from string to ptime -- but how to go from there to time_t ?

Comment: The problem with date_time is that a) you need the library (no header-only version) and b) no wstring support.