# Convert SQLite Date Field to C++ Time_T

Tags: c++, sqlite, date, time-t

How Do I Convert A SQLite Date in the following format to a C++ Time_T Variable?

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856551/c-converting-a-datetime-string-to-epoch-cleanly), which discusses a few approaches.  In particular, if you have access to Boost, you can use `<boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>` and create a `boost::posix_time::ptime` object from a string of the format in your question.  (See the first answer in that question.)

Alternatively, you can use [`strptime()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/321812/2530166).

Example:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

std::size_t timestamp_to_seconds(const char* timestamp)
{
    std::tm tm_struct;

    strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm_struct);
    // You can control daylight savings time if necessary.
    tm_struct.tm_isdst = 1;
    std::size_t t = std::mktime(&tm_struct);

    return t;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << timestamp_to_seconds("2013-07-05 12:34:56") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Running this example gives the following output:

```
$ ./a.out
1373042096
$ date -d "2013-07-05 12:34:56" +%s
1373042096
```

As you can see, it agrees with the `date` utility.  (I assuming you are on a platform with access to `strptime`.)  You may have to be careful when handling daylight savings or timezone info...I had to use `tm_struct.tm_isdst = 1` to force recognition of daylight savings and get agreement with `date`.

Comment: Is there a better date time type function for C++ I am very new to the language and time_t was the first thing I found. I tried using the boost library, but when trying to use it I get a lot of compile errors. I don't know if it is the library or my lack of understanding.

Comment: Hi Talon06, please see my edit for a short example.  Hopefully you can modify it to suit your exact purposes.

Answer (score 0):

`time_t` is a Unix timestamp (seconds since 1970-01-01), so you have to convert with [strftime](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```sql
SELECT strftime('%s', '2013-07-05 12:34:56');
```

The result is a string, but you can read it as an integer value.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in the application or do I need to query against that database?

Comment: It might be a good idea to store the dates in the database in the `time_t` format in the first place. If you really want to convert them inside your program, see RyanMck's answer.

Comment: Yes, it was a little unclear whether the conversion was supposed to take place via C++ or SQLite.  Certainly the SQLite conversion is a easier.