# A function (homemade or Windows API) that takes a date/time string into a SYSTEMTIME structure?

Tags: c, datetime

I receive a date/time string from Windows.

On a US computer, here is an example of the string:

TimeBegin  : 6/19/2014 7:49:43 AM

On a UK computer, this is the same string:

TimeBegin  : 19/6/2014 07:49:43

Is there a function that can take either these strings and put it into a standard format? Ultimately I want to send it to a SYSTEMTIME structure.

Comment: More than the string is needed to determine how to parse it, for example, if the date is June 7, 2014 the strings would be `6/7/2014` and `7/6/2014`, respectively -- both legal dates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [strptime() equivalent on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321849/strptime-equivalent-on-windows)

Comment: Possibly useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/856598/557362