# Is it possible to get the time (of the day) and date at time of compilation?

Tags: c++, c, windows, unix, compilation

What are the possibilities to know at compile time the time and date (BUILDTIME) in order to include in the binaries (executable/libraries) the information about the moment in which they have been created, in a portable way?

We have currently a solution that uses sh.exe, and requires to install msys under Windows, but I was wondering if it was possible doing without it.

Searching things like "build time/date", "compile time/date" did not lead to any relevant result.

**Edit:**

When I got to know about `__TIME__`, it was then possible to find this question had previously been asked: [Recording the time when you compile a source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455189/recording-the-time-when-you-compile-a-source)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard macros `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` do the job.

Be careful that this will provide you the *compilation date* of the file where they are used. Not the link date. Thus, you have to `touch` the file each time it is build, or do a pre-build step in MSVC.

[The C99 standard says](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> **6.10.8 Predefined macro names**
>
> The following macro names shall be defined by the implementation:
>
> - `__DATE__`: The date of translation of the preprocessing translation unit: a character string literal of the form "Mmm dd
>     yyyy", where the names of the months are the same as those generated
>     by the asctime function, and the first character of dd is a space
>     character if the value is less than 10. If the date of translation is
>     not available, an implementation-defined valid date shall be supplied.
> - `__TIME__`: The time of translation of the preprocessing translation unit: a character string literal of the form "hh:mm:ss" as
>     in the time generated by the asctime function. If the time of
>     translation is not available, an implementation-defined valid time
>     shall be supplied.

I copied the C99 text here, but these macros are much older than C99... I did not manage to find the standard text for older C...

Comment: Not only GCC or MVS support these macro's, but any ANSI C compiler.  In practice you can assume that all C/C++ compilers support these.

Comment: @meaning-matters and Matthieu: Would it be possible to reference that? This is the closest I could find: http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.10.8.html

Comment: @Antonio: coding-guidelines.com does not look to be more _official_ (regarding the C standard) than the GCC/MSDN documentation I copied in my post. I updated my post with a reference to the latest ISO standard (publicly available).

Answer (score 1):

You could use macros like `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`. This is also portable for Visual Studio (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could always write a 5-line program that calls `time` and `strftime` and outputs that to a file, rather than using `sh`. [I have used this approach for updating "build numbers" and/or "version number" in the past].

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` macros you can pass the value to your program at build time using a macro.

In your Makefile you can pass the date at build time in a macro:

```
gcc -Wall -DBUILD_TIME=`date +%d%m%y_%T` tst.c -o tst
```

(or use any other `date` format)

then stringify in your code:

```
#define STR(x) STR1(x)
#define STR1(x) #x

printf("%s\n", STR(BUILD_TIME));  // display build time
```

Comment: Nice one, but I don't think is portable to Windows/MinGW, is it?

Comment: build>gcc -Wall -DBUILD_TIME=`date +%d%m%y_%T` tst.c -o tst
gcc: +%d%m%y_%T`: No such file or directory  . . . . . . .     tst.c:4:8: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant . . . . . . . . . 
tst.c:4:16: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant. . . . . . .  Can it be you have something else installed? How do I get a new line in the comment box?!? :)

Comment: @Antonio You need to put the backquotes to enclose the `date` command as in my example.

Comment: They are there, but they have been "eaten" by the formatting... If I put backquotes in the comments, `it becomes like this`

Comment: @Antonio I initially put `STR(DBUILD_TIME)` instead of `STR(BUILD_TIME)`, I think it was the cause of your error.

Comment: No, I am afraid that was not the problem