# date and time manipulation in c++

Tags: c++, date

So, I want to do a class Delivery like this:

```
class Delivery{
private:
    string recipient;
    time_t date;
}
```

So, the date is time_t. The thing I want to do is let the user type the delivery date. Maybe the delivery is made today, maybe tomorrow, maybe next month. I could've made the date attribute string date instead of time_t. Why I didn't do that? Because, I have a list of deliveries and I want to sort the deliveries and then to print the deliveries that were made in a certain period. For example, print the deliveries made from 12.03.2013 until 25.08.2013.

The question is: how can I let the user set the date? I searched the Internet but I didn't found any useful functions. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: [boost.Date_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/date_time.html)  may be suitable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a string variable containing time to time\_t type in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213326/how-to-convert-a-string-variable-containing-time-to-time-t-type-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you read the input into a string named `time_string` in the format `01/01/13`:

```
struct tm tm;
strptime(time_string, "%D", &tm);
time_t t = mktime(&tm);
```

If you include the full year, e.g. 01/01/2013, replace `strptime(time_string, "%D", &tm);` with `strptime(time_string, "%m/%d/%Y", &tm);`. `%m` is the month, `%d` the day, and `%Y` the full year, e.g. 2013 instead of 13. Also note that if `time_string` is an `std::string` instead of a C-style string, you need to replace `time_string` with `time_string.c_str()` in the call to `strptime`.

Sources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11213640/2097780 and http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r12.bpxbd00%2Fstrptip.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Working on date/time involves using the `struct tm` and `time_t` data structures.

To convert `time_t` to `struct tm`, there are a few differnt functions, such as `localtime()`, `gmtime()`, etc.

To convert from `struct tm` to `time_t`, you use `mktime()`.

Obviously, you'll also need to write some code that reads year, month, day and perhaps hours and minutes from the user as integer values, then fill in a `struct tm` with the relevant values, and call `mktime()` to convert it to "seconds since 1 jan 1970" in a `time_t` value.

All functions to do this are declared in [`<ctime>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using C++, you might want to consider using: [Boost DateTime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time.html).

Answer (score 0):

I made a portable date-time class to solve this problem and it is called [xDateTime](https://github.com/ZenulAbidin/xDateTime). The way I created the constructors allows you to create a combined date-time object with nanosecond resolution:

```
#include "x_datetime.h"

void foo() {
    // Create 2020-02-29T15:30:30.100Z
    DateTimeD a_date(2020, 2, 29, 15, 30, 30, 100*1000*1000);
}
```

And it has a `strptime`-like function for importing custom dates:

```
#include "x_datetime.h"

void foo() {
    // Create 2020-02-29T15:30:30.100Z
    DateTimeD a_date;
    a_date.FromString("2020-02-29T15:30:30.100Z",
            "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3Z"); // %3 reads nanoseconds up to 9-digits
}
```

This will enable you to read any kind of date input.

It also includes adapters to convert between `std::chrono` times and Boost.DateTime times as well as some others.