# Convert a time (UTC ) given as a string to local time

Tags: c++, string, pointers, visual-c++, time.h

I have a time string like this "132233" (Time only no date) and i want to convert it into local time.
So, in order to use the function localtime(), I first converted my string into time_t using mktime() (thanks to [How to convert a string variable containing time to time_t type in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213326/how-to-convert-a-string-variable-containing-time-to-time-t-type-in-c) )and then printed the time after conversion using strftime as shown in (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/)
I am getting a serious run time error. Can any one please tell me whats wrong. Thanks in advance

```
int main()
{
    string time_sample="132233";

    std::string s_hrs (time_sample.begin(), time_sample.begin()+2);                                                 
    std::string s_mins (time_sample.begin()+2,time_sample.begin()+4);
    std::string s_secs (time_sample.begin()+4,time_sample.begin()+6);

    int hrs = atoi(s_hrs.c_str());
    int mins = atoi(s_mins.c_str());
    int secs = atoi(s_secs.c_str());

    struct tm time_sample_struct = {0};
    time_sample_struct.tm_hour = hrs;
    time_sample_struct.tm_min = mins;
    time_sample_struct.tm_sec = secs;

    time_t converted_time;
    converted_time = mktime(&time_sample_struct);

    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer[80];
    timeinfo = localtime(&converted_time);
    strftime(buffer,80,"%I:%M:%S",timeinfo);
    puts(buffer);                                                               
    cout<<endl;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your call to `sscanf_s` is expecting the input values to be colon separated and they're not.

Comment: thanks..my bad, ive corrected the code now..but nevertheless the issue still exists :(

Comment: %d%d%d won't work, since the function will see "132233" as a single number...

Comment: modified the code quite a bit;)..but the run time error is stubborn..have i used mktime correctly?

Comment: Tried to use strptime? Seems the correct solution here. You get struct tm *tm, Using mktime you can convert that to time_t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that if `time_t` is a 32 bit value, the earliest possible date it's capable of encoding (given a 1970-1-1 epoch) is 1901-12-13.

However you're not setting the date fields of your `tm` struct, which means it is defaulting to `0-0-0` which represents `1900-1-0` (since `tm_day` is 1-based, you actually end up with an invalid day-of-month).

Since this isn't representable by a 32-bit `time_t` the `mktime` function is failing and returning `-1`, a situation you're not checking for.

Simplest fix is to initialise the date fields of the `tm` struct to something a `time_t` can represent:

```
time_sample_struct.tm_year = 114;
time_sample_struct.tm_mday = 1;
```