# How to get input from cin, which are seperated by colon?

Tags: c++, time

I am trying to get time input like 12:30:00 which is hour:minute:second and then put them in a struct. Im using cin but it only works when i use space instead of colon like 12 30 00. How can i make it work with colon instead of space? Please be as easy as possible im very newbie about this.

An example could be like:

```
struct time{
    int hour,minute,second;
    long acc_seconds;
}tm;

int main(){
cout <<"Please enter date as HH:MM:SS";
cin >> tm.hour>>tm.minute>>tm.second;
}
```

Comment: For starters, check out [How to convert a string variable containing time to time_t type in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213326/how-to-convert-a-string-variable-containing-time-to-time-t-type-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a place holder object to read the `':'` into. Read the numbers into the right objects.

```
char dummy;
cout << "Please enter date as HH:MM:SS";
cin >> tm.hour >> dummy >> tm.minute >> dummy >> tm.second;
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the old is better

```
scanf("%d:%d:%d", &tm.hour, &tm.minute, &tm.second);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can store time in `String` and then divide it into hr,min,sec based on position of 2 colon and then store it in 3 integers.