# is this a bug in std::get_time?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to parse a date-time string and put the result into a std::tm structure. Below is the code,

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::stringstream ss;
struct std::tm when;

ss.str("8/14/2015 3:04:23 PM");
ss >> std::get_time(&when, "%m/%d/%Y %r");
```

After run the code, the when.tm_hour is 27. Is this a bug, or I did something wrong?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 on windows 7.

Thanks.

Comment: Weird, I can't get that to work in g++ at all and Ideone is failing to parse basic dates and times. I'm curious what's going on here.

Comment: Clang/libc++ says 15. GCC/libstdc++ fails to parse. This is fun.

Comment: Try imbuing a different locale before `get_time`. i.e. `ss.imbue(std::locale("en_US"));` I'm not sure which locales Windows supports, or if it expects `en-US` vs. `en_US`. You might have to play around to find one.

Comment: Normal usage would involve using `ss.imbue(std::locale(<something>))` before streaming.   Since the operation can fail, check `ss.fail()` before printing `when.tm_hour`.

Comment: Using `%T` instead of `%r` seems to resolve this problem (and yield a problem with the "seconds" instead).

Comment: Using `%H : %M : %S` instead of `%r` seems to provide a sustainable solution.

Comment: A fairly recent version of  `gcc` happily compiles the code (assuming it is put inside a function, of course) and set a failure flag on the stream, leaving the value untouched.

Comment: Looks like this problem is cause by the "PM" in the string. If it's changed to "AM", everything is OK. Did the developer add 24 instead of 12?

Comment: the ss.fail() returns false.

Answer (score 5):

You are running into a bug in Microsoft's implementation of the `std::num_get::do_get` function, specifically the section which parses the AM/PM (`%p`) part of the time:

```
    case 'p':
        _Ans = _Getloctxt(_First, _Last, (size_t)0, ":AM:am:PM:pm");
        if (_Ans < 0)
            _State |= ios_base::failbit;
        else
            _Pt->tm_hour += _Ans * 12;
        break;
```

The problem is that _Getloctxt returns an int in the range [0,3] and not in the expected range [0,1].

This bug has been reported to Microsoft (ID:[808162](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808162)) who claim to have fixed it in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Looks like it might fail with `Am` or `Pm` too, since it appears to be case sensitive.

Comment: Good point. Using `Am` or `Pm` causes the streams `failbit `to be set. Ironically, using `Am` actually results in the correct time being set, unlike `am`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that answered my question.