# Is std::get_time broken in g++ and clang++?

Tags: c++, c++11, time, c++14

I was working with some time functions today and noticed that the standard conversion using `%r` (or `%p`) does not seem to work for input via `std::get_time()` on g++ or clang++. See [this live code version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ca6eaa098e14db4) for g++ and clang++.  It *does* seem to work as expected under Windows with VC++ (see this [closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019209/is-this-a-bug-in-stdget-time)).  Also note that the effect is the same whether or not the `imbue` line is included.  The locale on my Linux machine is set to `"en_US.UTF-8"` if it matters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

int main(){
    std::tm t{};
    std::stringstream ss{"1:23:45 PM"};
    ss.imbue(std::locale(std::cin.getloc(), 
             new std::time_get_byname<char>("en_US")));
    ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%r");
    if (ss.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Conversion failed\n" << std::put_time(&t, "%r") << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << std::put_time(&t, "%r") << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be a libstdc++ issue.  clang with libc++ parses this fine.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: You're [right](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e597ffb8e4d4497e).  Should I retitle the question?

Comment: It looks like the [implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/locale_facets_nonio.tcc?revision=219012&view=markup&pathrev=219013#l654) doesn't handle `%r` or `%p`. If there's another place where they're supposed to be handled, I can't find it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the commenters have pointed out, this is actually a bug (an omission) in `libstdc++`.  A [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71367) has been submitted.

Answer (score 4):

The bad news is that `get_time()` is more broken than the OP and the commenters thought. It definitely does not work with the `"%F"` format specifier (dates in ISO-8601 format, e.g. `"2019-01-13"`) either. I modified the OP's code slightly to demonstrate this. Compiled with `g++` version 7.3.0, under Ubuntu 18.04.1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

int main(){
    std::tm tdate{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1}; // was t{};
    std::istringstream ins{"2019-01-13"};
    ss.imbue(std::locale(std::cin.getloc(), 
             new std::time_get_byname<char>("en_US")));
    ss >> std::get_time(&tdate, "%F");
    if (ss.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Conversion failed\n" << std::put_time(&tdate, "%F") << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << std::put_time(&tdate, "%F") << '\n';
    }
```

This is the output:

```
Conversion failed
1900-01-00
```

A minor remark: it is highly advisable to zero out the `std::tm` object before any processing is attempted.

Update: here is a workaround which relies on the UNIX function `strptime` (note that this is not a C or C++ standard function!). I show the code example with the ISO8601 date parsing.

First, let's detect the GNU `stdlibc++` library and pull in the `<time.h>` header. (On some platforms the header may be `<sys/time.h>`):

```
#include <cstddef>
#if defined(__GLIBCXX__) || defined(__GLIBCPP__)
#define GET_TIME_WORKAROUND
#include <time.h>
#endif
```

Then parse:

```
#ifdef GET_TIME_WORKAROUND
char *result = strptime(datestr.c_str(), "%F", &_cal);
if (result == nullptr) {
    throw std::invalid_argument{ "Date(" + datestr + "): ISO-8601 date expected" };
}
#else
// proper C++11
// ........
```