# Why does get_time fail to parse what put_time produces?

Tags: c++, datetime

I am getting incorrect results using `get_time` to parse a date with a `PM` modifier.

To be sure that I am using the correct modifier (even though it should not depend on the locale at all), I generate the time using `put_time` in this example code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Initialize time from 24-format
    tm tm;
    strptime("16:33:45", "%H:%M:%S", &tm);

    // Define 12h time format
    string fmt("%I:%M:%S%p");

    // Convert time to 12h format and print - looks good!
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << put_time(&tm, fmt.c_str());
    cout << oss.str() << endl;

    // Read time in 12h format
    istringstream iss(oss.str());
    iss >> get_time(&tm, fmt.c_str());

    // Result is wrong!
    cout << iss.fail() << " (Fail)" << endl;
    cout << tm.tm_hour << endl;

    // Read time in 12h format using strptime
    strptime(iss.str().c_str(), fmt.c_str(), &tm);

    // Result is correct!
    cout << "Correct" << endl;
    cout << tm.tm_hour << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
04:33:45PM
1 (Fail)
4
Correct
16
```

See also https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c4f75f14fdf53095

I have come across an (unconfirmed) GCC bug from 2018 which reads very similarly, namely, https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84216. Also, I have found [is this a bug in std::get_time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019209/is-this-a-bug-in-stdget-time) which according to the only answer is related to some Microsoft implementation I am not aware of using.

`strptime` is able to parse the time correctly.

Is this a bug somewhere, or am I using `get_time` incorrectly?

Comment: I think I have basically come across https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71367.

Comment: I can confirm the the Microsoft libraries of MSVC2022 do not exhibit that problem: `iss.fail()` is 0, and `tm.tm_hour` receives the expected value. (Disclaimer: I commented out the `strptime` lines and manually set fields of `tm`, because MSVC has no support for `strptime`). So it is probably related to the link you gave in comment...