# trying to use std::get_time to parse YYMMDD and failing

Tags: c++, visual-c++, std

I'm trying to do this and failing:

```
std::istringstream ss("1212");
ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%y%m");
if (ss.fail()) // every time!
```

this works ok:

```
std::istringstream ss("12-12");
ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%y-%m");
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong? what can i use otherwise as windows doesnt appear to have a srtptime

windows/vs13
TIA

Comment: Doesn't work in VS2015 either.

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio does not seem to implement the spec properly, nor did [GCC until version 5.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54354#c9). If you continue to use `std::get_time` with VS13 or even VS15, you will need to manually add delimiters to be able to parse times until they finally get around to realizing this bug.