# Difference between two timestamps in days C++

Tags: c++, timestamp, timespan

I have timestamps in the format (**Year.Month.Day**) in an XML file.

I need to find out the difference between two timestamps in days.

**Sample Timestamps:**

```
<Time Stamp="20181015">

<Time Stamp="20181012">
```

How can I find the number of days between the above timestamps?

Number of days = `date2 - date1`. I am considering all the days (don't need to skip weekends or any other day). Time-zone does not matter as well.

**PS:** I understand that I have to parse the timestamp from XML. I am stuck in the logic after parsing value.

**Update-1:** `std::chrono::year` and other such things are part of C++20. But I get a compilation error:

> namespace "std::chrono" has no member "year"

Comment: 1. Define "day". 2. Have you had a look at any of the [C++ date handling functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)?

Comment: @tadman: I have updated my question. I am not sure how do I use `chrono` library in this case since I already have my timestamps in an XML file.

Comment: It's not a library per-se, it's built in to C++. You're going to have to extract the value from XML using an XML parser of your choosing, then work that date into one of the date parsing functions or use an external date computation library.

Comment: The reason I asked to define "day" is if time-zones are a factor then days become complicated. If it's just calendar difference then it's a lot easier.

Comment: C++20 will make this easy to do with just the standard library. In the meantime, maybe Boost's Date Time library? [Example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.days_alive) for calculating the days between two time points.

Comment: @tadman: I just need a simple calendar difference.

Comment: @Galik: I am not sure how to use it. The `std::difftime()` expects the arguments in  `std::time_t` and my Timestamps look different.

Answer (score 1):

You can use C++20's syntax today (with C++11/14/17) by downloading [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source date/time library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).  Here is what the syntax would look like:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    istringstream in{"<Time Stamp=\"20181015\">\n<Time Stamp=\"20181012\">"};
    const string fmt = " <Time Stamp=\"%Y%m%d\">";
    sys_days date1, date2;
    in >> parse(fmt, date1) >> parse(fmt, date2);
    cout << date2 - date1 << '\n';
    int diff = (date2 - date1).count();
    cout << diff << '\n';
}
```

This outputs:

```
-3d
-3
```

If you don't need time zone support (as in this example), then `date.h` is a single header, header-only library.  [Here is the full documentation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html).

If you need time zone support, that requires an additional library with a header and source:  tz.h/tz.cpp.  Here is the [documentation for the time zone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html).

Comment: I think that I do not have C++20 can I still use it?

Comment: You'll need C++11 or later.

Comment: I am trying to build it but I am getting errors regarding C and CXX compilers. One of the error is "CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found."

Comment: For this operation, all you need to do is `#include "date/date.h"` and point your compiler at the `date/include` directory.  No need to worry about building the date lib.

Comment: Silly question but I am not really able to understand the line `in{ "<Time Stamp=\"20181015\">\n<Time Stamp=\"20181012\">" }`. Moreover, after parsing the string from XML, I will be having the Timestamps in the separate string variables.

Comment: The stuff in quotes is just a string literal that mimics a file.  The type that does that is called `std::istringstream`.  You can put any string you want to into a `istringstream`, and then read from that object as if it were a file.  You can use the date library to help you parse directly from your XML file, or if you prefer, from strings that you put into an `istringstream`.

Comment: I need the result in integer value. Since the result is in `sys_days`, I tried to convert it to the string first (so that I can remove `d` at the end) but I am not able to do that. Please suggest how can get the number of days in integer value.

Comment: @skm:  I've updated the answer to extract an `int` from the `std::chrono::duration`.  `sys_days` is a `std::chrono::time_point`.  The difference between two `sys_days` is a `std::chrono::duration`.  For a video tutorial on `std::chrono` see:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Comment: It worked on a simple project but when I incorporated into my actual project with the same simple procedure of including header files, I got 68 errors [(Screenshot of errors).](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CJywFBjz30o9fxqOoq_UcR3HLIppjvTy/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Try `#define NOMINMAX` just prior to `#include <Windows.h>`.

Comment: Then some other header is turning `NOMINMAX` back on.  The Windows headers like to create `min` and `max` macros which trash C++ functions by the same names.  You could try including date.h first.  The date.h line number on your first error corresponds to the declaration of `year::min()`.

Comment: I tried to include `date.h` first then `windows.h` (with and without `NOMINMAX`) but same errors.

Comment: You may want to search stackoverflow for "NOMINMAX" for help with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is the old fashioned way:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip> // std::get_time
#include <sstream>

// ... 

std::string s1 = "20181015";
std::string s2 = "20181012";

std::tm tmb{};

std::istringstream(s1) >> std::get_time(&tmb, "%Y%m%d");
auto t1 = std::mktime(&tmb);

std::istringstream(s2) >> std::get_time(&tmb, "%Y%m%d");
auto t2 = std::mktime(&tmb);

auto no_of_secs = long(std::difftime(t2, t1));

auto no_of_days = no_of_secs / (60 * 60 * 24);

std::cout << "days: " << no_of_days << '\n';
```

Comment: I got `0 days` as output with the above code. Furthermore, the compiler is not able to resolve `>>` operands. It says `more than one operator matches these operands`.

Comment: Yes, it compiles and generates wrong output. And, in my VS2015 code, I see red highlights below `>>`, which says `more than one operator matches these operands`. I already included `iomanip`

Comment: @skm Are you using `C++11`?

Comment: @skm I think VS2015+ has a bug with `std::get_time`... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041344/trying-to-use-stdget-time-to-parse-yymmdd-and-failing