# Calculating difference between two times in C++

Tags: c++

I want to calculate difference between two given times ( in the format "HH:MM xm" where 'xm' is either 'am' or 'pm' )

What i have tried so far is :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// Function Declarations
int ComputeDifference(int startHr, int startMin, int endMin, int endHr, bool isAM1, bool isAM2);// 6 parameters
// Main Function
int main()
{
    //Declaring Variables
    int startHour, endHour, startMinute, endMinute, Minutes, Hours;
    bool isAM1 = false, isAM2 = false;
    char AM1, PM1, AM2, PM2, colon, answer;
    //Function Calls and a loop
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter start time, in the format 'HH:MM xm' where 'xm' is niether 'am' or 'pm': " << endl;
        cin >> startHour >> colon >> startMinute >> AM1 >> PM1;
        cout << "Enter future time, in the format 'HH:MM xm' where 'xm' is niether 'am' or 'pm': " << endl;
        cin >> endHour >> colon >> endMinute >> AM2 >> PM2;
        if ((AM1 == 'a') || (AM1 == 'A'))
            isAM1 = true;
        if ((AM2 == 'a') || (AM2 == 'A'))
            isAM2 = true;
        Minutes = ComputeDifference(startHour, startMinute, endMinute, endHour, isAM1, isAM2) % 60;
        Hours = ComputeDifference(startHour, startMinute, endMinute, endHour, isAM1, isAM2) / 60;
        cout << "There are " << ((Minutes) + (Hours * 60)) << " minutes (" << Hours << " hours and " << Minutes << " minutes) between " << startHour << colon << startMinute << AM1 << PM1 << " and " << endHour << colon << endMinute << AM2 << PM2 << "."<< endl;
        cout << "Do you want to run another session? (y/n): ";
        cin >> answer;
        if (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
        {
            isAM1 = false;
            isAM2 = false;
        }
    } while ((answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y'));
    return 0;
}
```

//Function Definitions

```
int ComputeDifference(int startHr, int startMin, int endMin, int endHr, bool isAM1, bool isAM2)
{
    int difference = 0;
    if ((isAM1 == true) && (isAM2 == false))
    {
        if (startHr == 12)
        {
            startHr = 0;
        }
        difference = (((endHr - startHr)*(60)) - ((startMin)-(endMin)));
        return difference;
    }
}
```

But for calculating difference between 3:45 pm and 12:56 am , it is giving me this output :   "There are 1 minutes (0 hours and 1 minutes) between 3:45pm and 12:56am."

[image]

I'm not getting where i am wrong. I'm new to C++ so my apologies if I'm missing anything obvious.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to convert your times to something like "number of minutes since midnight" then subtract them and convert back?
Code would surely be shorter and easier to understand.

Comment: Not a duplicate but should give a few ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52820227/difference-between-two-timestamps-in-days-c

Comment: it may be shorter and easier to understand , but for now could you please tell me where am i wrong in my code ?

Comment: @VishalSrivastav, it seems, like this is the error: `if (startHr = 12)`. It's assignation, not comparison. So, in this `if` `startHr` becomes `12` and it goes inside, where it becomes `0`. In other words, `startHr` will always be equal to `0` after this `if`'s body.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake , but it is still giving me same output

Comment: @VishalSrivastav, I have one more idea about the issue here: `12am` and `12pm` is being treated incorrectly. They are needed to be either swapped from `am` to `pm` and wise-versa or being treated as `0 hours`.

Comment: @VishalSrivastav, I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
int ComputeDifference(int startHr, int startMin, int endMin, int endHr, bool isAM1, bool isAM2) {
    if (startHr == 12) isAM1 = !isAM1;
    if (endHr == 12) isAM2 = !isAM2;

    int start_time = startHr * 60 + startMin + (isAM1 ? 0 : 12 * 60); 
    int end_time = endHr * 60 + endMin + (isAM2 ? 0 : 12 * 60);
    int difference = end_time - start_time;
    return difference > 0 ? difference : 24 * 60 - difference;
}
```

[Test](https://wandbox.org/permlink/j2flXHyx3NV60Eus)

Comment: Your code is giving this "There are 1609 minutes (26 hours and 49 minutes) between 3:45pm and 12:56am."  It is still wrong..