# does std::get_time have a bug?

Tags: c++, g++

I'm solving a problem on a site. My code is the following:

```
string timeConversion(string s) {
    std::tm t = {};
    string result = "";
    std::istringstream ss(s);
    
    ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%I:%M:%S%p");
    if (ss.fail()) {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << std::put_time(&t, "%H:%M:%S")  << endl;
        result = oss.str();
    } else {
        result = "Parse failed";
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

When I input **07:05:45PM** it returns **07:05:45**. But I expect **19:05:45**. What is wrong?

**UPDATE**

The code is wrong for "if" statement. It must be

```
string timeConversion(string s) {
    std::tm t = {};
    string result = "";
    std::istringstream ss(s);
    
    ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%I:%M:%S%p");
    if (ss.fail()) {
        result = "Parse failed";
    } else {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << std::put_time(&t, "%H:%M:%S")  << endl;
        result = oss.str();
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

The code returns **"Parse failed"** for **"07:05:45PM"** (g++ 5.4.0) It's unexpected too.

Comment: It does have some bugs in VS it seems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041344/trying-to-use-stdget-time-to-parse-yymmdd-and-failing

Comment: Shouldn't the `ss.fail()` be negated?

Comment: @KamilCuk: yes, you are right https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time.
But why it parse wrong if i change the code?

Comment: So it just fails for `07:05:45PM`. Now the question is what is the correct input for `%p`.

Comment: When I fix the problem noted by Kamil Cuk, this code returns "19:05:45" for me. Using Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.8.8)

Comment: I'm using g++ 5.4.0, and i have the problem with `%p` too.

Comment: I found this bug reproducible [online](https://onlinegdb.com/Bye_X-thX) on some services. Strangely, `strptime(s.c_str(), "%I:%M:%S%p", &t)` works.

Comment: @KamilCuk: strptime works as expected. Thanks! So it's a bug.

Comment: clang produce "19:05:45"  gcc "Parsed failed"

Comment: curiosly enough, gcc fails even with the example in cpp reference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in gcc https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71367

Bold emphasis is mine.

> Ed Beroset 2016-05-31 21:17:27 UTC
>
> Created attachment 38616 [details]
> Short program demonstrating lack of %r support in std::time_get
>
> **The "%r" and "%p" formats don't seem to be supported yet for time_get**, even though they are both supported by time_put.  The %p is supposed to be the locale's version of "AM" and "PM" (if any) and %r is equivalent to %I:%M:%S  %p in the POSIX locale.

The last comment its saying:

> Jakub Jelinek 2021-04-27 11:37:54 UTC
>
> GCC 11.1 has been released, retargeting bugs to GCC 11.2.