# Take a time given in form hh:mm:ss and get hours minutes and seconds as an int

Tags: c

I have tried using:

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &hour, &min, &sec);
printf("%d %d %d", hour, min, sec);
```

but it does not work, I think I have to bypass the ":" but am unsure how to do this.

Cheers

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
if (scanf("%d:%d:%d", &hour, &min, &sec) != 3)
    …error handling…
```

Comment: Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213326/how-to-convert-a-string-variable-containing-time-to-time-t-type-in-c).