# Does there has any easy way to convert "02:00" to minutes say 120?

Tags: c++, time

Does there has any easy way to convert "02:00" to minutes say 120 ?

Do we have to split it to 2 and then * 60 ?

Comment: `Do we have to split it to 2 and then * 60 ?` Yes.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213326/how-to-convert-a-string-variable-containing-time-to-time-t-type-in-c

Comment: @YSC I'm unsure about the dupe.  There is no need at all to convert the string into a `time_t` to just have to do more math to convert it's hours and minutes into total minutes.  We can do that directly from the sting like `((time[0] - '0') * 600) + ((time[1] - '0') * 60) + ((time[3] - '0') * 10) + (time[4] - '0')`

Comment: That's true, it might answer OP's question, but it is no certainty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to split anything here.  In `"12:34"` the `1` represents the tens of hours, the `2` is how many single hours, the `3` is the tens of minutes and the `4` is the single minutes.  Knowing that you can multiply each position by how many minutes it represents.

If we have

```
std::sting time = "12:34"
```

then `(time[0] - '0') * 600` would give use 600 minutes (`time[0] - '0'` converts the character `'1'` to the number `1`).  `(time[1] - '0') * 60` would be 120 more minutes.  If we keep going we'd have

```
((time[0] - '0') * 600) + ((time[1] - '0') * 60) + ((time[3] - '0') * 10) + (time[4] - '0')
```

And all of that added up gives use 754 minutes.  You can put that into a function if you have to do it multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it using [Howard Hinnant's date/time library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date):

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    istringstream in{"02:00"};
    minutes m;
    in >> parse("%H:%M", m);
    assert(m == 120min);
}
```

Additionally this should port to the upcoming C++20 spec by simply removing `#include "date/date.h"` and `using namespace date;`.

The advantage of this technique includes:

- No need to manually split the string
- No need for manual conversion from hours to minutes
- The result goes straight into the `chrono` type safe units
- No need to dip down to the old C API

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you like this one:

```
std::tm tm = {}; 
std::stringstream ss("20:05");
ss >> std::get_time(&tm, "%H:%M");
std::cout << tm.tm_hour * 60 + tm.tm_min << std::endl;
```

Maybe it is much to much overhead using this big library calls in your case, but maybe you have to deal with more complex time strings.