# Unable to convert string with seconds from epoch to date_time

Tags: c++, datetime

I have a string containing the seconds from the epoch, how do i convert this string to a format
as such -

> YEAR-MONTH-DAY HH:MM:SS

Here MONTH should display the month number and DAY gives the day number. Also the time needs to be in 24 hour format.
For example :

> 2019-06-26 11:14:25

I have tried using strptime but havent been successful in doing so, could someone help me in what I am doing wrong.
This is what i have tried so far

```
int main()
{
    string timee = "12341234534";

    const char *ptr = timee.c_str();
    struct tm tim;
    strptime(ptr, "%S", &tim);
    time_t abcd = mktime(&tim);

    cout<<abcd;
    return 0;

}
```

Found this code snippet on another stackoverflow link
[How to convert a string variable containing time to time_t type in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213326/how-to-convert-a-string-variable-containing-time-to-time-t-type-in-c)

Comment: Tell us what exactly have you tried (your code)

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName.. I have added the code please check. Thank You!

Comment: A [`strptime` manual or reference](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) should be very useful. Don't *guess* when programming, it will seldom work well.

Comment: Also note that the "input" operator `>>` stops on *space*. You can't use it to read lines containing spaces.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I'll check the manual and try, Thank You!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, i dont need lines, just a string containing the seconds from epoch (eg - 12341234534) is enough

Comment: Lastly, `strptime` is not a standard C or C++ function. You might want to read about [`std::get_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) to read and parse the input.

Comment: For future questions please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). What that should tell you is to (among other things) include the input to your program (unless it could be hard-coded which is even better) and also the expected and actual output of the [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing, but I think I figured out what you want...

If the time is in a `time_t` compatible format, then just read it directly into a `time_t` variable, and convert it through [`std::localtime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) so you can output it in the wanted format using [`std::put_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time).

Something like

```
std::time_t time;
std::cin >> time;
std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&time), "%F %T") << '\n';
```