# How to convert a string in format HH:MM:SS to time_t in C?

Tags: c, time.h

How can I convert a command line argument in the format of HH:MM:SS thats a string into a time_t type?
The only solutions I've found have been for C++ and to convert time_t into string but not the other way around in C.

Thanks.

edit: I need to implement it without string.h

I'm trying to convert a command line argument and a string (e.g."13:32:41" and "13:40:35") into a time_t format so I can use difftime(tm1,tm2) to get the difference.

Would the below work?

```c
time_t string_to_time(const char* time) {
  struct tm tm = {0};
  sscanf(time, "%H:%M:%S", &tm.tm_hour,&tm.tm_min, &tm.tm_sec);
  time_t t=mktime(&tm);
  return t;
 }
```

Comment: You have to parse the string e.g. using `sscanf`.

Comment: strtok()  function may help

Comment: Maybe `strptime` and `mktime`, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strptime.html. Note that a `time_t` is usually the time since 01 Jan 1970, but you have a time only without date. You should [edit] your question and explain what result you want to get, maybe using examples of input and expected output.

Comment: Edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

> Would the below work?

Yes (for valid input). It will return number of seconds at `1970/1/1 HH:MM:SS` since `1970/1/1 00:00:00`.

But I do not get the point. Is it really soooo hard to write:

```
int hour, min, sec;
if (sscanf(time, "%d:%d:%d", &hour, &min, &sec) != 3) return -1;
return hour * 3600 + min * 60 + sec;
```

> to convert time_t into string but not the other way around in C.

My first google hit [How to convert a string variable containing time to time_t type in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213326/how-to-convert-a-string-variable-containing-time-to-time-t-type-in-c) uses `strptime` is indeed for C++. Sadly `strptime` is not [part of C time.h](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono), it comes from [POSIX strptime](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strptime.html) available on linux and such. For windows, see ex. [strptime() equivalent on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321849/strptime-equivalent-on-windows) .