# C++ String to DateTime Functions

Tags: c++

Coming from C# I'm a bit lost with the datetime functionality in C++. I am simply looking to convert from a string in the format 2023-01-12T07:00:00+08:00 to the number of seconds since 1-1-2023 UTC.

And the reverse, i.e. an int of the number of seconds since the start of 2023 to a string in the format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z". Any code or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Have tried various options using chrono and time_t which seems to work:

```
std::time_t getTime(const std::string& dateTime) {
    std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::seconds> tTime;
    std::istringstream stream(dateTime);
    std::chrono::from_stream(stream, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", tTime);
    return std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tTime);
}

const time_t EPOCH_2023 = getTime("2023-01-01T00:00:00+00:00");

int stringToIntTime(const std::string& dateTime) {
    return static_cast<int>(getTime(dateTime) - EPOCH_2023);
}
```

to get the int.

But I haven't a clue on doing the reverse.

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate, but it looks useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021388/how-to-parse-a-date-string-into-a-c11-stdchrono-time-point-or-similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I recommend:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
constexpr std::chrono::sys_seconds EPOCH_2023 = std::chrono::sys_days{2023y/01/01};

int
stringToIntTime(const std::string& dateTime)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    sys_seconds tTime;
    istringstream stream(dateTime);
    stream >> parse("%FT%T%Ez", tTime);
    return (tTime - EPOCH_2023)/1s;
}

std::string
intToStringTime(int i)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    sys_seconds t = EPOCH_2023 + seconds{i};
    return format("{:%FT%T%Ez}", zoned_time{"Etc/GMT-8", t});
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int i = stringToIntTime("2023-01-12T07:00:00+08:00");
    string s = intToStringTime(i);
    cout << i << '\n';
    cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Which should output:

```
946800
2023-01-12T07:00:00+08:00
```

I've taken the liberty of simplifying your `stringToIntTime` somewhat:

- Your `EPOCH_2023` constant can be made more efficient by storing it in a `sys_seconds` type as opposed to a `string`, and making it `constexpr`.  In the object code this will just be a integral literal which is the count of seconds between your epoch and the `system_clock` epoch of 1970-01-01.
- `stringToIntTime` is correct, but I've simplified it down to one function and used `parse` in place of `from_stream` just for slightly cleaner syntax.  `parse` is a slightly higher level API.
- Also note the use of `%Ez` in place of `%z`.  The former includes the `:` separator between the hours and minutes of the UTC offset.
- There's no need to go through the C API with `time_t`.  One can just subtract the parsed UTC time `tTime` from your epoch.  This results in seconds since your epoch.  To convert that to `int`, just divide by 1 second.
- `intToStringTime` starts with converting the `int` to seconds and adding that to your epoch.  This gives `t` the type `sys_seconds` and the value of a `time_point` with seconds since the `system_clock` epoch.
- Finally just format `t`, using a time zone with the +08:00 UTC offset, using the desired format.  Note the use of -8 in the name to give +8 for the offset.  This is simply [POSIX weirdness that IANA inherits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  If some other time zone is desired, just sub that in for `"Etc/GMT-8"`.
- Note the use of `%T` which is a shortcut for `%H:%M:%S` and `%F` which is a shortcut for `%Y-%m-%d`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to use sscanf_s (stdio.h since C11) or strptime (POSIX standard) to convert the string into either individual values or a tm type (time.h), respectively. From there you can use mktime (time.h) to get back a time_t type. Then just subtract them. [How to convert a string variable containing time to time_t type in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213326/how-to-convert-a-string-variable-containing-time-to-time-t-type-in-c)

Comment: No, they've used `std::chrono` to go one way, it'd be much simpler to stick with `std::chrono` to go back again